# Problems in Installing Ubuntu through wubi.exe file

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, wubi

I am using Windows 7 32-bit OS. I want to dual-boot Ubuntu alongside it.

I downloaded wubi.exe file but when I try to run it after asking for username and password details, I get an error message which says,

```
An error occured:

Could not retrieve the required disk image files

For more information, please see the log file c:\users\dell\appdata\local\temp\wubi-12.04-rev272.log
```

I don't understand the text in the log file.

Comment: Could you paste the relevant section of the log file to the bottom of your question (add <pre> before the code and </pre> after it to make it display properly

Comment: Please help us help you by providing requested information. If you have solved this question yourself, please answer it so that others can benefit from your experience. Thank you.